# Does Entity Framework Core always seed data in migration scripts if HasData(someData) is in the IEntityTypeConfiguration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I wish to seed data *manually* if the environment is 'development' or the database doesn't exist in the database.

Using Entity Framework Core (v 7.x) I have a sample class like this:

```
internal class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.Ignore(u => u.FullName);

        var users = FakeUsers.CreateUsers();

        builder.HasData(users);
    }
}
```

Now, will this mean that the next time I run the tool to generate the (next) migration script, it will include seeding these `User`'s ?

Is it possible to only do it when the web application starts up?

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
public static IHost SeedDatabase(this IHost host)
{
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        using (var appContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>())
        {
            try
            {
                appContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log errors or do anything you think it's needed
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to seed data to database.");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    return host;
}

...

CreateHostBuilder(args)
    .Build()
    .SeedDatabase() // <---- HERE.
    .Run();
```

but even then, that would be every time the app starts?

Is this possible to do?